exponential map property
Consider $f:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $f(t)=\exp(it)$  Note, $f'(t)=i\exp(it)$ so $|f'(t)|=1$.
$|f(t)-f(s)|=\int_s ^t f'(t) dt \leq |t-s|$ for all $s,t\in [0,1)$
We know that $f$ has an inverse $g:f([0,1))\rightarrow [0,1)$.  Is $g$ locally lipschitz continuous?

Hint: $$|f(s)-f(t)|=2\left|\sin\frac{s-t}2\right|.$$

@AnneBauval I was thinking of this topologically, it wraps $[0,1)$. Your hint what is it supposed to suggest?

The answer is yes. You can even take some larger domain for $f$: any interval $I$ of length $L<\pi$, to make sure that $$\frac{|f(s)-f(t)|}2\le a:=\frac{|e^{iL}-1|}2<1\quad(\forall s,t\in I).$$
The identity
$$|f(s)-f(t)|=2\left|\sin\frac{s-t}2\right|$$
gives you immediately that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous (since $|\sin u|\le|u|$), but also helps you to deal with $g$:
$$|s-t|=2\arcsin\frac{|f(s)-f(t)|}2\le\frac1{\sqrt{1-a^2}}|f(s)-f(t)|,$$
hence $g$ is even globally $\frac1{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$-Lipschitz continuous.
